# Is there a way to extract which rows in your data are satisfying each quadrant of a confusion matrix in R?

Tags: r, extract, confusion-matrix

I am generating a Random Forest model for a two classification problem (0 and 1) and I want to extract the rows of my training and validation sets of the model and see which rows of the data correspond to each quadrant of my calculated confusion matrix. Is there a way to create variables in the dataset and label each data point as "Predicted: 1, Actual: 1" or the like? I want to know which data points are falsely positive, specifically.

```
# Create a Random Forest model with default parameters
model1 <- randomForest(failure ~ customer_count+    mfgr_yr+    age+    kva_rating+ existing_phasing+   manufacturer+   mounting+   owner_name+ secondary_nominal_voltage+  secondary_voltage_connection+   structure_mounting+ type_vl+    primary_nominal_voltage+    existing_phases+    temp70+ temp80+ temp90+ temp40+ temp30+ temp20+ humidity75+ humidity85+ humidity95+ wind6+  wind10+ wind15+ rain01+ rain07+ rain15+ percentoverloaded
,data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE, cutoff = c(.08,.92))
model1
```

```
# Predicting on train set
predTrain <- predict(model1, TrainSet, type = "class")
# Checking classification accuracy
table(predTrain, TrainSet$failure)  


# Predicting on Validation set
predValid <- predict(model1, ValidSet, type = "class")
# Checking classification accuracy
mean(predValid == ValidSet$failure)                    
table(predValid,ValidSet$failure)
```

This is how I set up my confusion matrix. I do not necessarily need to have a new variable in the dataset, I just need to be able to see which rows of data correspond to each quadrant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying not to overthink a very simple problem, I propose something very simple:

```
predTrain <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
TrainSet <- data.frame(failure=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))

which(predTrain == 1 & TrainSet == 1)
which(predTrain == 1 & TrainSet == 0)
which(predTrain == 0 & TrainSet == 1)
which(predTrain == 0 & TrainSet == 0)
```

Or if you really want a new column

```
# example data
predTrain <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
TrainSet <- data.frame(failure=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))

# building a new row in TrainSet

TrainSet$confusion <- 10 * predTrain + TrainSet$failure
print(TrainSet)

# alternatively

TrainSet$chrConfusion <- paste0(predTrain, TrainSet$failure)
print(TrainSet)
```